# Child inside Column shrinkwrap when height is short and scrollable when height is overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Let say there is a Column widget that is always fits its children size. The ContentWidget is a widget with dynamic size. And the ContentWidget is showing with its height when the height is short than the screen size; and will allow scrolling when its height is reaching the screen size overflow.

Is there any way I can obtain this layout?

I have faced this kind of design quite many times, the easiest solution i have used is to use MultiChildLayout to get the height during the build and call its rebuild again, but this is not a good solution as this required to draw once. Just want to know if there is any more precise way to do this. Thank you!

Eg.

Short:
[image]

Long:
[image]

white color background is the whole screen.
red + yellow is the column

red + yellow is showing as its height unless yellow is too high that let the Column(red+yellow) is larger than the screen (white area), then the yellow part will be scrollable

**Update:**
I have tried following code, but the the singleChildScrollView will overflow the bottom. Do you have any advice?

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Text('header'),
          SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Text(
                  'long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text')),
          Text('footer'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Not 100% sure I understand your question. Layout questions it’s usually helpful to show a picture of the problem and to phrase the question in the context of your problem. instead of asking for a specific a/b that might not actually be the correct approach to the goal. Happy to take another look if you revise.

Comment: Thank you, @Kent. Hope this is easier to understand for you. :-)

Comment: Tran has responded with the correct answer. See his below. You simply put the scroll view in the CenterWidget. Because the footer is fixed you don't need to worry about size. If the footer was needing to move deepening on CenterWidget size it would be more difficult.

Comment: @Kent, it seems this method is not able to scroll when it is overflow. Do you have any suggestion? thanks!

Comment: Wrap the center widget in single child scroll view

Comment: You won’t have other content besides the text inside the scroll view?

Comment: It is one of the example case. it may be Text only or even if other widgets, but all of them are widget with dynamic height.

Comment: You should put the scroll view around your column

Comment: well, i am not the designer, i hope i can change it :-), but as i said this is a common design. its ok if there is no other solution, i just want to seek if there is a better precise solution.

Comment: Sorry I read that code wrong. Please try with some contains ect. Inside the scroll view it should scroll them fine

Comment: It’s very strange to have text as the top level under scroll

Comment: Like you almost always want other things in there with it

Comment: Not sure where your background is from? If you are familiar with web almost everything layout is done with div then text inside that. In flutter it’s container. I have this exact layout working fine. But I have containers with text inside them.

Comment: @Kent would you show your demo in the answer how you have successfully obtain that? And i do received a design with text-only .

Comment: I have to finish some things for work. If you don’t have an answer by later today I will post one.

Comment: sure, just take your time and thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your example. The key you are missing is a Widget called **Flexible**. It's an important Widget for these types of cases you will learn about it after you have been doing Flutter dev for a while.

[image]

```
      import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final exampleText = Text(
      'long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text');
  List<Widget> content = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Center(child: Text('header')),
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: Column(children: content),
            )),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Center(child: Text('footer')),
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            content.add(exampleText);
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Official Flutter video about it.](https://youtu.be/CI7x0mAZiY0)

Comment: Thank you! normally Flexible may work for other widget, but SingleChildScrollView is not able to count the size of its child and will take the max height of the viewport. Using Flexible or Expanded in this case will take as much space as it can, it will not shrink when the child height is small, like this: https://imgur.com/a/PCsO7Or

Comment: Yeah you don’t need to shrink the scroll view to fit the content right? I didn’t see that anywhere in the requirements

Comment: Yes, the scroll view (or the center widget) is required to fit the content height when it is short; only scrollable when it is long enough to overflow.`red + yellow is showing as its height unless yellow is too high that let the Column(red+yellow) is larger than the screen (white area), then the yellow part will be scrollable`

Comment: @CbL It's not scrollable if the content is small in my demo. Do you also mean that the footer needs to move up and the scrollview size needs to become smaller in addition to not scrolling?

Comment: Yes, the yellow area showing its actual height (not the height after Flexible take up) when it is small.

Comment: @CbL See updated code, you just remove the mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween. That way the Column doesn't expand.

Comment: @CbL I updated the example. You can see by pressing the floating action button the column (inside the scrollview) will expand until the scroll view fills the parent. At that point it starts scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

```
      Container(
          color: Colors.yellow,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Text('header'),
              Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Text(
                      'afdfasff long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long  long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text'),
                ),
              ),
              Text('footer'),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

Comment: I have tried your method, it seems this method is not able to scroll when it is overflow, details updated in the question. Do you have any suggestion? thanks!

Comment: Thanks! i have tried your answer. the problem is that it is not able to show as content height when content is short. like this: https://imgur.com/a/ibo4bkM

Comment: sorry. I don't understand exactly what your problem is. The data is too short to not scroll, in my opinion that is reasonable.

Comment: there is 2 situations:
1. when the data is short ( ie. the whole Column is not overflowed), center text widget will show exactly its height (not including the expanded area by Expanded)
2. when the data is long enough to overflow, then only center text widget will be scrollable

case 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xc3i.png
case 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqXzY.png

Comment: Let's replace Expand with flexible.

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  // Add this line
  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
  // If there was an AppBar, subtrach with AppBar().preferredSize.height
  // and maybe you need to subtract with status bar height: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top
  // E.g. MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - AppBar().preferredSize.height - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top
  color: Colors.yellow,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      Text('header'),
      SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Text(
              'long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text')),
      Text('footer'),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: Thank you! but the problem is that if we use the singleChildScrollView like this, the text part is not able to scroll like the screen cap i uploaded on the question.